# Is it Possible to achieve Multiple Inheritence in ruby?

Tags: ruby, multiple-inheritance

I have doubt whether we can achieve multiple inheritence using 'module' concept or Is there any other keywords or concepts which achieve multiple inheritence in ruby?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ruby supports mixin composition. A class can only inherit from *one* superclass, but it can mix in *many* modules.

That's not, strictly speaking, multiple inheritance, but it offers at least sharing of behavior across different classes.

Comment: And it's in my opinion much better than multiple inheritance.

Comment: However, MI is, in some sense, more powerful. Not in the computability theoretic Turing Machine sense, of course, but relating to expressivity: you can trivially implement mixins using MI (and, in fact, mixins are a pretty common idiom in Eiffel, Python and C++), but you can't implement MI using mixins. OTOH, it is quite easy to screw up MI very badly. *cough* C++ *cough* But, it's not impossible to get right as Eiffel clearly shows. Remember: if C++ is all you know, then judging MI is like judging all Americans when the only one you know is Glenn Beck or judging all cars by a Pinto.

Comment: I shouldn't have brought up a topic I'm not too familiar with, great comment. :)